# How to add cypress into my current docker?

Tags: docker, vue.js, docker-compose, cypress

I have got a docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    expose:
      - "8080"
```

And a Dockerfile

```
FROM node:7.7.2-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json .

RUN npm install --quiet

COPY . .
```

Now I want to add cypress (https://www.cypress.io/) to run test by running:

```
npm install --save-dev cypress
```

But maybe it doesn't work because I can't see the cypress folder.

After installing cypress, I run

```
/node_module/.bin/cypress open
```

I can't see cypress open.

So now I don't know how to add cypress to my docker to run testing on my host by cypress.

Comment: They have official docker images: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images

Comment: @Yuankun: I know but It can't run on my host

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running into a similar issue with a similar set up

The way I temporarily fixed it was by manually going into the folder containing my `node_modules` folder and running `node_modules/.bin/install`, from there you should be able to open it with `node_modules/.bin/open` or `$(npm bin)/cypress open`.

Tried setting up a separate cypress container on my docker-compose as such

```
cypress:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: docker/cypress
    depends_on:
        - node
    volumes:
        - .:/code
```

with the dockerfile being Cypress's prebuilt docker-container

Was able to get `docker-compose exec cypress node_modules/.bin/cypress verify` to work, but when I try to open Cypress it just hangs.

Hope this helps OP, but hope someone can provide a more concrete answer that will help us run Cypress fully through docker

Comment: that means I have to add a new service for my docker-compose and add a cypress Dockerfile?

Comment: @ken that's the part I had trouble figuring out, if you do it my way with the local cypress installation you don't need anything that has to do with docker (since cypress can run independently of your app). It's more of a hotfix so you can start writing test files and such for now.

However that doesn't seem ideal as cypress should be able to be run and automated as a part of docker. I believe I'm missing some config to get cypress working from docker properly. Hopefully someone else can help!

Comment: I know when I install local machine. It works well, but I want to install it for my docker. Anyway thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

If you're using docker-compose, the cleaner solution is to just use a separate, dedicated Cypress Docker container, so your `docker-compose.yml` becomes:

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    build: .
    entrypoint: npm run dev
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/app
      - /usr/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
  cypress:
    image: "cypress/included:3.2.0"
    depends_on:
      - web
    environment:
      - CYPRESS_baseUrl=http://web:8080
    working_dir: /e2e
    volumes:
      - ./:/e2e
```

The `e2e` directory should contain your `cypress.json` file and your `integration/spec.js` file. Your `package.json` file doesn't have to include Cypress at all because it's baked into the Cypress Docker image (`cypress/included`).

For more details, I wrote a comprehensive tutorial on using Docker Compose with Cypress:

- ["End-to-End Testing Web Apps: The Painless Way"](https://mtlynch.io/painless-web-app-testing/)

Comment: This is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

You can also use an already existing cypress image on docker hub and build it in docker compose. Personnaly I avoid adding it directly in compose, I create a separate docker file for cypress.